# Do temporary dipoles form in silicon(IV) dioxide?

Tags: covalent-compounds

Textbooks only ever mention covalent bonds between silicon and oxygen atoms in silica. However, as electron movement is random, one end of a silicon atom in a given instant could be more positive than the other (setting up a temporary dipole) and this temporary dipole could induce dipoles in neighboring oxygen/silicon atoms. Could somebody confirm if this is indeed the case?

Comment: Temporary dipoles form ***everywhere***.

Comment: Temporary dipoles are induces even by other temporary dipoles, not talking about permanent dipoles.